# Initializing the base class to a derived base class?

Tags: c++, oop

I don't think this is possible, but if it is, I'd find it very usseful.

I'm making a Gui API where the user does the paint event. Lets say I want to make a Numeric TextBox. Well it would only seem good practice for it to inherit from TextBox. The problem with this, is that the user is then stuck to reimplement the paint event for the textbox since

```
TextBox::paint();
```

Would just call my default way of drawing it.

It would be annoying if they had to maintain all their TextBox derivatives.

Is there a way to get around this problem?

Lets say my TextBox paints a square, then the numeric part adds a circle, but the user's textbox, which derives from my TextBox draws a triangle, and my Numeric one derives from my TextBox I want the result to be triangle, circle.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not exactly clear but it almost sounds like you need to apply some variant of the bridge pattern here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I say in my comment, I think the bridge pattern is actually what you want, but since you're trying to insert a user's class as a base class for your NumericField thing the way you'd do THAT is to:

```
template < typename Base = TextField >
struct NumericField : Base
{
 ...
  void paint() { Base::paint(); draw_circle(); }
};
```

Now the user could use `NumericField<>` or they could insert their class:

```
struct UserField : TextField
{
  ...
  void paint() { draw_triangle(); }
};
NumericField<UserField> my_field;
```

The bridge answer would look more like so:

```
struct TextField
{
  TextField() : extender_(new null_extender) {}
  ...
  void set_extender(extender*);
  virtual void paint() { draw_square(); extender_->paint(); }
  ...
};

struct extender { virtual void paint() = 0; };
struct null_extender { void paint() {}};
struct numeric_extender { void paint() { draw_circle(); }};

struct UserField
{
  void paint() { draw_triangle(); extender()->paint(); }
};
```

Lots of details missing from that, but that would sort of be the story.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the only difference between NumericTextBox and TextBox that the former only allows the input of certain characters?  Do you want it to paint differently?

Comment: The point is it wil not user the User's paint event, theyd need to be able to do : public UserTextBox

Comment: What do you mean?  Where did UserTextBox come from?  Is that the name of the instance the user is creating?  The user creates a NumericTextBox if that's what he wants, and uses it just the same way as if it were a TextBox.  If they declare it as a TextBox but instantiate a NumericTextBox it will work fine, because paint would be virtual in any reasonable API.

Comment: Lets say my TextBox paints a square, then the numeric part adds a circle, but the user's textbox, which derives from my TextBox draws a triangle, and my Numeric one derives from my TextBox I want the result to be triangle, circle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure quite what you mean.  Your question is not that clear.

The title seems to be asking how to call the base class initializer or constructor, 
is that what you want?

If this is what you want then just like this.

```
class TextBox
{
  public:
  TextBox() { }
  virtual ~TextBox() { }

  virtual Paint() { }
};

class NumericTextBox : public TextBox
{
  public:
  NumericTextBox() : TextBox() { }
  ~NumericTextBox() { }

};
```

Make sure the base class for TextBox::Paint and any other methods are declared virtual as well as the destructor.

Comment: No sorry this is not what I meant, I meant if you could initialize A() as a derived A() like when you do base* = new derived;